# Subclassing in objective c and viewWillAppear message delegates?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, subclass

I might be confused here and asking the wrong question.

If I use a class like the UISplitViewController inside the appdelete.m, will the only message i will receive is the message the UISplitViewController calls and not any VIEW message? for example:

in my myappdelegate.m

```
....
UISplitViewController *mySplitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];

mySplitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:leftside,rightside,nil];
 ...

mySplitViewController.delegate = self;
....
[windows addSubView:mySplitViewController.view];
....
 -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {
 }
```

in myappdelegate.h I included UISplitViewControllerDelegate

I expected viewWillAppear to fire but it is not. I assume if I had subclass UISplitViewControler it would have fire. right?

BTW: I am doing this without using IB. Do I need to set the target for the mySplitViewController?

What I want to do is setup the orientation of the splitviewcontroller when it rotates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `viewWillAppear` method and other view related methods will be called on the view or view controller themselves, not on the delegate.
That means that if you make a subclass of `UISplitViewController` called `SplitViewControllerSubClass`, the `view...` methods will be called on the instance of `SplitViewControllerSubClass`, not on the delegate object.
But considering you are creating the views and displaying them programmatically, you already know exactly when the view will appear (i.e., right before you add it to the window), so I believe you could do whatever setup you want at that point.

Comment: Is it by default that the UIViewcontroller autoresizes it subview? I have two viewcontrollers for the UISplitViewController and only one of them is showing up. See updated post.